# 'Cannot find module fluent-ffmpeg' on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm running a video processing script on AWS Lambda.

While it seems to work perfectly locally (tested using [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local)), I'm having a strange issue when it runs on Lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'fluent-ffmpeg'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:364:17)",
    "require (module.js:380:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/processing.js:2:14)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:456:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:356:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:364:17)"
  ]
}
```

The ZIP I am uploading contains the following files:

```
~$ find . -maxdepth 2
.
./bin
./bin/ffmpeg
./config.js
./event-samples
./event-samples/custom.js
./event-samples/dynamodb-update.js
./event-samples/kinesis.js
./event-samples/s3-put.js
./frames
./Gulpfile.js
./index.js
./node_modules
./node_modules/async
./node_modules/aws-sdk
./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg
./node_modules/gulp
./node_modules/gulp-awslambda
./node_modules/gulp-zip
./package.json
./processing.js
./utils.js
```

(The buggy require is located in *processing.js*)

If I open the ZIP, `node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/*` does exist.

I tried to include the module using:

- `require("./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index")`
- `require(__dirname + "./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index")`
- `require(process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT + "/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index")`

But none of these solved the problem. I also tried reinstalling node and npm on my machine, `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` (just in case).

Since Lambda runs Node 0.10.36, I also tried using this version on my machine to do the `npm install`, but that doesn't change anything either.

Help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try the [AWS fork instead](https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg)?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this library is for resizing and generating video thumbnails, right? In that case that does not apply to what I need to do (extracting each frame of a video)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. My development machine runs Windows 7, and that's apparently what caused the issue... Would be interested in the reasons, though.

Anyway, running `npm install` on a linux installation and uploading the code to Lambda did the trick.